# Is there anything like admin_notices for front end?

Tags: front-end, notices

I'm new to Wordpress and trying to take advantage of the framework as much as possible. On the front end, I want a centralized message area to display error, success, and general notices similar to how they're handled via admin_notices on the back end. I'm not seeing a similar hook for the front end.

I guess I'm asking which action should I be hooking into on the front end to mimic admin_notices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such action in the front end (in a theme) by default. Simply use a custom action like

```
do_action( 'theme_notices' );
```

and hook into this one.

Comment: Looking into this a bit further... If I'm wanting to make my plugin theme-independent, would it make more sense to set a global variable for the messages rather than using do_action? This way themes could output the messages from any location. If I understand correctly, do_action would be placed in a specific spot in the theme files. Ideally, I'd like to have the notices output during get_header action by default if the theme has no explicit integration with the plugin, but give themes the option to output in a different spot if desired. Does that make sense?

Comment: There's exactly _no_ such hook anywhere in a theme by default. Using a global would just pollute the namespace. And adding such a custom hook has the same effect (and can be used anywhere and multiple times) **plus** it doesn't throw around errors when your plugin isn't active and the global isn't set.